# Will GPU optimized model run on TPU?

Tags: keras, hardware

There is a [project](https://github.com/commaai/openpilot) which contains models in [DLC format](https://github.com/commaai/openpilot/tree/master/models) ([Snapdragon Neural Processing Engine - SNPE](https://developer.qualcomm.com/docs/snpe/index.html)) that I guess are optimized for the Qualcomm Snapdragon 820 chipset (see second link). The project newly also introduced models in Keras format. My question is - will the Keras model run on [Google Coral with Edge TPU](https://coral.ai/products/)? If so, how fast? Is it needed to optimize the model for TPU?